# what is the difference bettween the spring boot run Application and the run Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I find the situation I tried to clean adn start the main class,it started successfully.

I do not know why? But I find a strange problem is that: when you use the command of spring boot run, in my target directory,the all configuration files are not exist, and when I clean and then run the main class by run Application command, the all configuration files will appear in the target directory.

what is the difference between the spring boot run Application and the run Application?

Comment: Are you running the application from some IDE?

Comment: I run it successfully by intellij idea。I never run it once again .

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Comment: I find this ?but I don't know weather it is the reason?

Comment: The spring boot maven plugin does several things for you. You can check it out in the docs.